# How to reinstall apache and php in debian 5

Tags: php, linux, apache-2.2, debian

I'm newb in linux but I want to reinstall (old version not working now) php and apache in debian 5. I want PHP 5.3.

How to do this?

Thanx!

Comment: Isn't this a question for superuser.com? However there are several ways to do that. The one I prefer is compile php from source.

Comment: What to do if I'm newb? Is there any commands to do this?

Answer (score 0):

http://articles.slicehost.com/2009/4/9/debian-lenny-installing-apache2-and-php5

http://www.debiantutorials.com/how-to-install-upgrade-to-php-5-3-on-debian-lenny/

Answer (score 0):

Try using [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/), don't know if it can update apache, but you can use it to update lot of other stuff (It's a mangement system to the server)